# subprocess.run() running the arguments too

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writig a code for my mini-programs to be operateable with a single 'mds' command I can type to console. Everything works just fine except for one issue I'd like to have fixed, here is my code:

```
## Imports ##
import argparse
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import os

## Argparse Setup ##
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="mds")
parser.add_argument('subcommand', type=str, help='The Subcommand')
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*', help='The Subcommand Arguments')
args = parser.parse_args()

## Logging Setup ##
class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logFile = 'C:\mds\log.txt'
    
    def log(self, messg):
        with open(self.logFile, 'a') as file:
            file.write(f'[{datetime.now()}] {messg}\n')
            
    def clear(self):
        with open(self.logFile, 'w') as file:
            file.write('')
            
    def open(self):
        os.system('C:\mds\log.txt')
            
logger = Logger()
            
logger.log(f'Called module/function ({args.subcommand}) with arguments ({args.args})')

## Running the module ##
try:
    subcommand = args.subcommand
    subprocess.run(['python', f'C:\mds\{subcommand}.py', *args.args])
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f'Module {args.subcommand} not found!')
```

The problem is:
When I call log function (`mds log message`) it runs the log.py script just fine but then it tries to run message.py too. I can see that in my log:

[2023-08-01 22:26:21.568299] Called module/function (log) with arguments (['message'])
[2023-08-01 22:26:21.621123] Called module/function (message) with arguments ([]) --> The problem
[2023-08-01 22:26:21.660381] message

How do I do it so it won't try to run message.py too?
I get this unpleasant error message every time:

`python: can't open file 'C:\\mds\\message.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I tried to transfer the arguments using getArgs() function, that just returned the arguments to the other script, but that didn't work. I also tried a lot of solutions suggested by ChatGPT, but none of them worked either.

Comment: Taking user input and using that in a subprocess command is very bad practice. Why not use a switch statement and import your python files?

Comment: By the way, you should be using \\ instead of \.  You are lucky that in both cases, the character after the backslash isn't something that gets converted into a single character.

Comment: Can you add `log.py` to your post?

Comment: Is the name of this file log.py?  It looks like the subprocess command is calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding:

First, you run `mds log message`. (I'm guessing this does the same thing as running
`python C:\mds\log.py log message`.)

Since `log` is the subcommand argument, the script writes `Called module/function (log)` to `log.txt`, and `subprocess.run(['python', f'C:\mds\{subcommand}.py', *args.args])` is evaluated as `python C:\mds\log.py message`.

So now, `log.py` is running again (which means that `logger.log()` and `subprocess.run()` are both evaluated again), this time with `message` as the subcommand argument.

> How do I do it so it won't try to run message.py too?

I'm not really sure how the `mds log message` command is set up to run this script, but if you explain that then I can probably help. Or, hopefully this answer has provided enough information for you to figure out a solution. :)

Comment: Your understanding is right and `python C:\mds\log.py log message` really does the same thing as `mds log message`. My idea was that when I call mds, it opens the main.py with given arguments. So `mds log` is a command with one argument called subcommand, based on that it should call the subcommand.py script, or in this case, log.py. That allows me to add infinite amount of modules without changing the main script, because all it does is just calling the subprocess.py, so when I use `mds run` it just calls run.py with all the arguments given after the subcommand run.